# FTDI Chip Loopback Functionality

Tags: python, serial-port, usb, loopback, ftdi

I am using a C232HM-DDHSL-0 USB to MPSSE converter and would like to test its functionality without using another slave device.

I would like to try out the loopback functionality and have written some code to try it out. It is not working and I am not sure if my setup is incorrect or I am doing something wrong. 
Context:
-> I am using putty to see incoming data and send outgoing data
-> I have tried tying RX and TX together
-> The chip has a built in API where 0x84 turns on loopback functionality (see http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/AppNotes/AN_108_Command_Processor_for_MPSSE_and_MCU_Host_Bus_Emulation_Modes.pdf)
-> A copy of my script:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial(
    port = 'COM13',
    baudrate = 9600)

def main():
     #enable loopback
     command = bytearray([0x84])
     ser.write(command)
     # type 'cc'
     command = bytearray([0x39, 0x02, 0x00, 0x63, 0x63])
     ser.write(command)
     msg = ser.readline()
     print msg

 # call main function
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Thanks

Comment: what is the output you get? its a timeout or print junk values or it just wait indefinitely?

Comment: I am currently getting no input

Answer (score 0):

That loopback command is for the MPSSE mode and you're in the UART mode.